# Is this definition of infinite limits needlessly restrictive?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition

I am studying James Stewart's "Calculus: Early Transcendentals 7th Edition". On page 115, a precise definition of infinite limits is presented:

> Let $f$ be a function defined on some open interval that contains the number $a$, except possibly at $a$ itself.  Then
>
> $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \infty$
>
> means that for every positive number $M$ there is a positive number $\delta$ such that
>
> if $\hspace{1em}0 < |x - a| < \delta \hspace{1em}$ then $\hspace{1em} f(x) > M$

I am trying to understand why Stewart is limiting $M$ to the set of positive numbers.  This choice feels arbitrary and superfluous.  It seems to me that Stewart could just as easily have said "for all $M > 42$".

Is the word "positive" in the phrase "for every *positive* number $M$" required in this definition?  Why not just say "for every number $M$"?  Would the definition be any less precise?

Comment: To the question why $>0$ and not $>42$?  If you are going to set a marker, in this case zero is the natural place, right?  "Why not 42?" Why not 42,000 or some other number.  Anyway, why not negative numbers?  Well, we are trying to approach infinity and you want to consider M>-6,000 ?  Seems to be going in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any one of these phrases renders the definition unchanged:

1. "for every $M\in \mathbb{R}$"
2. "for every positive number $M$" (original definition)
3. "for every $M>42$" (undoubtedly, you chose this number as it is the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life).

It should be clear the definition with 1. implies 2. implies 3.

The definition with 3 implies  1 because if there is a $\delta$ such that $|x-a|<\delta\implies f(x)>42$, then the same $\delta$ works for any $M\leq 42.$ So they are all equivalent.

Comment: My visual intuition led me to believe that the phrase "for every real number $M$" would be no less precise.  Seeing $M > 0$ is a bit distracting for a novice like me.  Especially considering that $42$ is the more natural choice. ;)

Comment: @ntwk Oh, 42 is definitely a more natural choice :)